# Codeigniter-How do create html div elements in cntroller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter-How do create html div elements in controller and how to post that elements to view:
Is this correct:

```
$html='<div id="example">';
$html='example';
$html='</div>';
$data['ab']=$html;
$this->load->view('abc',$data);
```

and abc.php

```
<?php echo $ab; ?>
```

`<?php echo $ab; ?>` does not display anything
Is there any methods to create html elements in controller and how to print that elements in view

Answer (score 1):

You have to concatenate html using `dot` operator.

```
$html="<div id='example'>";
$html.="example";//concatenates with previous html 
$html.="</div>";
$data['ab']=$html;
$this->load->view('abc',$data);
```

Then in your view `abc.php`.

```
 <?php  echo $ab; ?>
```

There is also a built-in library for parsing html  in codeigniter.You can also use this.
For parser more see docs https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/parser.html

Comment: thanks for your replay.your code does not display anything

Comment: are you sure? where is your view abc.php.it must inside `application/views`.

Comment: Sure my abc.php in application/views folder .but does not display.i put 'echo $html;' in controller it will displayed with in <body> tags only not working <?php echo $ab; ?>

Comment: rather than sending data try $this->load->view('abc',$html); and in view echo $html.